# A stratified data set into 10 folds and each fold contain around 10 % of the data in R

Tags: r, cross-validation

I want to perform a 10 fold cross-validation in R where each fold contains around 10% of the data. There are 185 points which have to be spread out among the 10 folds.

```
id<- 1:185
```

The idea is to have each point in one of the folds. Basically, each fold has to be independent. I have tried to use the `createMultiFolds` function from the `caret` package where the split is done randomly (which is good) but some points are presented in several folds while others in none.

```
library(caret)
index_cv<- createMultiFolds(1:length(id), k=10, times =1)
```

There is also the function `createDataPartition` in the same caret package but again the folds are not independent from each other.

```
createDataPartition(id, times = 10, p = 0.1, list = TRUE, groups = min(5, length(id)))
```

Any would know how to achieve what I want?

Comment: You are sure to find good answers at an R-oriented forum such as Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your close. The function you want is createFolds. It will make each fold completely disjoint.

```
createFolds(id, k=10)
```